# Can't get QLabel image to scroll

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel, qscrollarea

I'm working on getting this `QLabel` image I set up that is working perfectly fine. I just need to get it to scroll. I understand the `QScrollArea` setup but this is not the typical use of `QScrollArea`.

I need to set up my scroll area in the `mainwindow.cpp` alongside my `QLabel`. This is the area where I set up my `QLabel` and where I want to set it up to be able to be scrollable.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QString filename = "C:/Users/SOYO/Desktop/Qt_GUI_C++/ParkOur/map.jpg";
    QImage image(filename);
    ui->labelMap->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));

    QScrollArea *scrollArea = new QScrollArea;
    scrollArea->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Dark);
    scrollArea->setWidget(ui->labelMap);
}
```

I don't know how to get `QScrollArea` to work without it taking complete control over the entire program and showing all the image.

I just need the image to be scrollable, and please give me example code, it makes everything much easier to grasp. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

P.S. I do not want the scroll to be over the main widget, just the `QLabel` widget with the image in it.

Comment: You might find some relevant information [at the question about qlabel showing an image inside a qscrollarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981662/qlabel-showing-an-image-inside-a-qscrollarea). I have not checked it in details though.

Comment: i figured it out finally, i eneded up just passing the label image in a new qscrollarea and then just positioning it from there with basic resize and move functions built in to Qt, I LOVE Qt AND ITS SIMPLICITY!